# SqlAlchemy relationship many-to-many to an other many-to-many

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

I have the following mapped class, which is an association coming from 2 other classes.

```
class InstanceCustomer(Base):
__tablename__ = 'Instances_Customers_Association'

cust_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Customers.id'), primary_key=True)
inst_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Instances.id'), primary_key=True)

customer = relationship(Customer, backref=backref('customer'))
instance = relationship(Instance, backref=backref('instance'))

def __init__(self, cust_id=None, inst_id=None):
    self.cust_id = cust_id
    self.inst_id = inst_id

def __repr__(self):
    return "<InstanceCustomer(cust_id='%s', inst_id='%s')>" % (self.cust_id, self.inst_id)
```

I would like to associate it to the class Person. So as 1 InstanceCustomer can have many Person and 1 Person can have many Instance Customer, I will need an other association between them, how can i do that? Is the primary-key/Foreign-key a problem as well?

Here is the class Person

```
   class Person(Base):
         __tablename__ = 'person'
         id = Column( Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a N:N relationship, you need a cross relationship table. A example:

```
Class A(Base):
    id = Column( Integer, primary_key=True)

Class B(Base):
    id = Column( Integer, primary_key=True)
    As = relationship(
        'A',
        secondary=AnB,
        backref=backref('Bs')
    )

AnB = Table(
    "table_a_to_b",
    Base.metadata,
    Column(
        'a_id',
        Integer,
        ForeignKey('A.id')
    ),
    Column(
        'b_id',
        Integer,
        ForeignKey('B.id')
    )
)
```

[Sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) doc for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just having a struggle because InstanceCustomer is having  already two primary keys, and I'm not able to deal with that

Comment: You don't need to use these two foreign keys as primary key. Use a auto increment int id as a primary key. Use unique key to ensure there will be only one (a_id, b_id) pair if you want.

Comment: So if i undderstand you (a_id,b_id) should NOT be a composed key, but should be indentified by an other primary key auto incremented. 
but my problem is that InstanceCustomer is composed by a composed primary key, which should be in the cross relationship table. But As i trying to import them, SQLAlchemy is complaining about : " there are multiple foreign keys path linking the table,etc..." But message persists even if i provided the foreign_key argument to the relationship